# Import error ModuleNotFound for Airflow aws_lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, airflow, airflow-2.x

I am using Airflow 2.2.5 and want to trigger an AWS lambda function.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM apache/airflow:latest

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir apache-airflow-providers-docker==2.5.0 boto3==1.21.45 apache-airflow-providers-amazon==3.0.0
```

And here is how I import aws_lambda Invoke:

```py
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.aws_lambda import AwsLambdaInvokeFunctionOperator
```

I followed the instructions in the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/aws_lambda/index.html#). But unfortunately the module can't be found.

Comment: The operator was only added in `apache-airflow-providers-amazon==3.1.1`. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually all provider packages can be installed via `apache-airflow` with the following addition:

```
pip install apache-airflow[docker,amazon]
```

Answer (score 0):

The operator was only added in `apache-airflow-providers-amazon==3.1.1` as @Oluwafemi Sule mentioned.

You can install newer aws operators with the following command:

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-amazon>=3.1.1
```